# Pyspark Convert Column of Lists to Nested Structure Column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to convert an ugly set of text strings into a representative PySpark dataframe. I'm stuck on the final step of converting a column that contains a list of strings to a column that contains nested structure of rows. For each string in a list, I normalize it to the same fields with a python dictionary comprehension.  When I try to then convert that via an `udf` on the column it fails.

My column 'records' contains lists of strings that are like this...

```
['field1, field2, field3, field4', 'field1, field2, field3, field4'..]
```

luckily the string structure is well-defined, containing strings and ints, so I have a Python dictionary comprehension that just splits and assigns names.

```
def extract_fields(row: str) -> dict:
  fields = row.split(",")
  return { 'field1': fields[0], 'field2': fields[1], ...}
```

this works fine on a single string as a conversion to a Row

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
Row(**extract_fields( sample_string))
```

So, I thought I could use a UDF to then convert the column into a column of nested structure.

```
nest = sqlfn.udf(lambda x: [Row(**extract_fields(row)) for row in x])
```

Normally I would add the type returned for the UDF, but I can't figure out how to indicate an Array of Rows. I don't get an error until I execute later.

So, now when I try to apply this to my dataframe,

```
test = df.select(nest(df.records).alias('expanded')
test.show(5)
```

I get this error:

```
expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for 
pyspark.sql.types._create_row)
```

The other questions I have found related to this error seem to indicate they have a type error in their dictionary, but in my case, my dictionary is types string and integer. I've also tried on a tiny example with just a list of single strings and get the same answer.

My expected outcome is that the new column 'expanded' be a column with a nested row structure, where an individual row in that column is like:

```
Row(expanded = [Row(field1='x11', field2='x12',...), Row(field1='x21', 
field2='x22',....) ] )
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** `pyspark.sql.Row` objects cannot be returned from an `udf`.

**Known shape**:

If the schema is well define and you won't `array<struct<...>>` as the result, you should use a standard `tuple`. In case like that, a basic parsing function could be implemented like this*:

```
from typing import List, Tuple

def extract_fields(row: str) -> Tuple[str]:
    # Here we assume that each element has the  expected number of fields
    # In practice you should validate the data
    return tuple(row.split(","))
```

and provide an output schema for the `udf`:

```
schema = ("array<struct<"
          "field1: string, field2: string, field3: string, field4: string"
          ">>")

@sqlfn.udf(schema)
def extract_multile_fields(rows: List[str]) -> List[Tuple[str]]:
    return [extract_fields(row) for row in rows]

result = df.select(extract_multile_fields("x"))
result.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|extract_multile_fields(x)                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[field1,  field2,  field3,  field4], [field1,  field2,  field3,  field4]]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If the number of fields is large you might prefer to construct schema programmatically over using DDL string:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, StructField, StructType

schema = ArrayType(StructType(
    [StructField(f"field$i", StringType()) for i in range(1, 5)]
))
```

In Spark 2.4 or later you can also use built-in functions directly :

```
from pyspark.sql.column import Column

def extract_multile_fields_(col: str) -> Column:
    return sqlfn.expr(f"""transform(
        -- Here we parameterize input with {{}}
        transform(`{col}`, s -> split(s, ',')),  
        -- Adjust the list of fields and cast if necessary 
        a -> struct(
            a[0] as field1, a[1] as field2, a[2] as field3, a[3] as field4)
    )""")


result = df.select(extract_multile_fields_("x").alias("records"))
result.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|records                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[field1,  field2,  field3,  field4], [field1,  field2,  field3,  field4]]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Unknown shape**:

If the shape of the data is unknown then `array<struct<...>>` is not the right choice of the `DataType`. In case like that you can try to use `array<map<..., ...>>`, this however require all values to be of the same type:

```
from typing import Dict

def extract_fields(row: str) -> Dict[str, str]:
    return ... # TODO: Implement the logic

@sqlfn.udf("array<map<string, string>>")
def extract_multile_fields(rows: List[str]) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    return [extract_fields(row) for row in rows]
```

---

* Please note that all records has to be of the same shape. If some fields are missing. You should fill the gaps with `None`.